# Keeping git submodule history separate from containing repo history

Tags: git, git-submodules

If I have a git project Consumer with a git submodule repo called Producer, is there any way to keep the commit history from the submodule (Producer) seperate from the containing git repo (Consumer)?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a submodule allows you to keep it separate from its parent repo.

`Consumer` would record a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in its index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) to Producer, that is a *fixed* SHA1.

Even if you [instruct that submodule to "follow" a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309), a checkout of `Consumer` will *not* immediately update `Producer` (a separate  `git submodule update --remote` is needed)

A submodule is there to allow a repo to reference another repo at a fixed point in the submodule repo history (see "[true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309)")